# Displaying element on page load - using current URL

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm rusty at javascript and HTML, and trying to get back into it.

Here's the sample code of the element I'd like to modify:

```
      <div class="table">
         <h1>Container</h1>
         <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>                 
         </ul>
         <div id="tab_container">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab_content"></div>
            <div id="tab2" class="tab_content"></div>
            <div id="tab3" class="tab_content"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

This is a simple tab structure that I'm using. I can already control which tab I display.

I'd like to be able to control which tab is displayed when arriving on this page, based on the current page URL. 
For example, if the url was something like

> .../index.html#2

I'd like the second tab to be shown.
Is is possible to do so using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with simple CSS, using the `:target` pseudo-selector:

```
.tab_content {
    display: none;
}
.tab_content:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Or, if you wanted to use JavaScript:

```
.tab_content {
    display: none;
}

document.querySelector(document.location.hash).style.display = 'block';
```

Or, perhaps:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tab_content'), function (tab) {
    tab.style.display = tab.id === document.location.hash.substring(1) : 'block' : 'none';
});
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:target`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo).
    JavaScript:
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`UrlUtils.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hash)
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've got a function like the following:

```
function showTab(tabNumber) { ... }
```

In order to get the value after the hash mark, you just use this code:

```
var current = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Then you can simply pass `current` to your function:

```
showTab(current);
```